# Adding a game map to Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am someone who hasn't touched the Google Maps API, but as a Web Developer, I am starting to think of reasons to use it.  I wanted to mess around with it by adding a multiplayer FPS game map (say a map from Battlefield 3) and then putting markers and things on it.

That way I could share it with friends to show them hiding spots and they could add their own etc...

Obviously this is probably tons of work and I don't expect to be told exactly how to do it, but I am having trouble starting given that I would be working on a custom map and not the normal maps.

Thanks!

Comment: So what *exactly* is your question (hint use a question mark)?  You've given a super broad idea of what your plans are, but you haven't said *specifically* what you need help with.  If this doesn't make sense, please read the [What kind of question should I *not* ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) in the FAQ.

Comment: Do you want to add 3D elements like buildings i would recommend looking at google earth API for that. http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/firstpersoncam/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps API is not the API you want to be using to create your own custom maps. Rather people use Google Maps for their websites to give a visual display of locations and data relative to those locations for viewers to further understand the maker's purpose.

With that said, if your video uses a map that actually exists in the real world, you may be able to create a similar display using the Google Maps API. There are certain things you cannot do however, like remove the Google watermark, or create your own, so in that sense, the API may not suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, shortly after posting this I realized I might be better off just going straight HTML5 canvas and trying to mimic the google maps interface somewhat... we shall see how that turns out...